# Android calendar app that does not use stock Android Calendar Storage

Tags: android, calendar

Are there any Android calendar apps that do not use the stock Android Calendar Storage?

Even for typical *offline calendars*, Android stores the data in its own Calendar Storage.

I'm looking for solutions that do not use Android's Calendar Storage at all.

I am interested both in options that are completely offline and those that sync to a server.

I am not interested in solutions that require you run your own server, unless it is a push-button server that can be set up on a gratis host in 5 minutes.  In other words, I'm not interested in solutions that require running your own 24/7 server or paying for hosting just to have a working calendar.

I prefer gratis solutions, but will consider solutions that have a one-time payment.  Please, nothing with monthly service fees.

I prefer something that will allow .ics imports/exports and that allows multiple calendars, but those are preferences, not requirements.

The only solution I have found thus far is *Jorte*, but the UI is confusing, it does not allow .ics imports/exports (only .csv), and it requires a monthly fee to have more than one calendar.

Comment: Are you concerned over the *storage* – or the fact of Google syncing? I'm using *Business Calendar*, which comes with its own system (for calendar syncing). Didn't check for where it stores its stuff locally, though … And there's [HK calendar](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.HKKalender), promising a totally private one without sync. Plus there's always [my list of calendar apps](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_calendar_general#group_55) :)

Comment: @Izzy Both. I don't want (or need) Google syncing.  Unfortunately, Business Calendar appears to have a serious bug that when Google sync is blocked it is impossible to edit/delete individual events that are part of a recurring event.  They claim it is an Android bug and that the solution is to enable syncing.

Comment: Oh. I have GSync blocked here, but I don't remember when I've edited such an event last – no issues here with BC & DAVDroid & ownCloud. Maybe when I have some spare time I could check that – but even if it "works for me", that must not mean anything for you :(

Comment: @Izzy BC blames it on Google, so possibly using DAVDroid & ownCloud eliminates the bug for you; I've looked into DAVDroid & ownCloud, but it looked like it would take a number of hours to learn and setup... plus the time and cost of finding a hosting service.  Although it looks good, the time & monetary cost outweighed the benefit.

Comment: Not really. I've bought myself a BananaPi with a small SSD, all together ~100€ (without SSD, it would be about 60€ for hardware), that now is my "home server" (eating less than 2W). ownCloud setup is a few minutes. Can also act as media server, and more. Found it worth the money :) To reach it from the outside, a simple dyn-host (e.g. no-ip.org) does the job. As for the bug: might well be I've just not encountered it as I have few recurring events and cannot even remember having edited individual items of those.

Comment: another step at going googleless. slightly off topic, but id like to ask is there a contact app that doesnt use contact storage?. it doesnt feel right asking a question i got an idea from

Comment: @FONZ I'm good if you want to ask that question, or if you prefer me to post it, I can do that as well.  Just let me know.

Comment: @RockPaperLizard: itd be nice if you could post the question. i doubt the rest (like phone storage and the like) are as flexible

Comment: @FONZ Sure, no problem.  Here you go: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/29892/android-contact-app-that-does-not-use-stock-android-contact-storage