# Android contact app that does not use stock Android Contact Storage

Tags: android, contact-manager

Are there any Android contact apps that do not use the stock Android Contact Storage?

It can include an integrated dialer, or rely on an external one.

I am interested both in options that are completely offline and those that sync to a server.

I am not interested in solutions that require you run your own server, unless it is a push-button server that can be set up on a gratis host in 5 minutes or is a simple server that can be run on-demand. In other words, I'm not interested in solutions that require running your own 24/7 server or paying for hosting just to have a working contacts server.

I prefer gratis solutions, but will consider solutions that have a one-time payment. Please, nothing with monthly service fees.

I prefer something that will allow vCard imports/exports, but this is a preference, not a requirement.

*Many thanks to @FONZ for the encouragement to write this question.*

Comment: I know there was something like that for calendars, don't remember for contacts. Still, my usual recommendation when it comes to Android apps: while waiting for good answers, be welcome to check my lists – in this case: [Contact Managers and Dialers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_dialer). I thought *DW contacts* had this, but cannot find it in its app description anymore.